# How to use a fixture in py.test?

Tags: python, pytest

I am missing probably something obvious, but I do not see it.

I have the file `conftest.py` in where I define a fixture:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def file_tests():
    return "tests.json"
```

And then I have my test as follows (file `test1.py`) in the same folder as `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):

    def test_basics(self, file_tests):
        print(file_tests)
```

But when I run

```
py.test test1.py
```

I get an error

```
E       TypeError: test_basics() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file_tests'
```

What obvious thing am I missing?

Maybe it is "interfering" with the `seleniumbase` class?

Comment: Apparently the test case methods aren't supposed to take any arguments.

Comment: But I have some other pytest code, where I created the test in exactly that way!

Comment: `seleniumbase` uses `unittest` underneath, subclassing `unittest.TestCase`. `pytest` support of using fixtures with `unittest`-style tests is very limited, see [unittest.TestCase Support](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/unittest.html). When subclassing from `TestCase`, you can inject fixtures as test case instance attributes, see [my other answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375022/2650249).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixtures wont work with test classes inheriting from `BaseCase` since it is a [subclass of `unittest.TestCase`](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/fixtures/base_case.py) and pytest [doesn't support fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/unittest.html) for `unittest.TestCase`.